# Javascript: Transforming an Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some data which looks like this:

```
let wheredata = [ { "field": { "field": "email", "datatype": "STRING", "inputtype": "text", "model": "User" }, "operator": "Op.eq", "value": "myuser@gmail.com" }, { "field": { "field": "createdAt", "datatype": "DATE", "inputtype": "date", "model": "User" }, "operator": "Op.gt", "value": "2015-12-12" } ]
```

I'm actually building a dynamic sequelize query where clause using this data and it is supposed to look like below:

```
{
      email: {[Op.eq]: 'myuser@gmail.com'},
      createdAt: {[Op.gt]: '2015-12-12'}
    }
```

Here is my code to do this:

```
let key, key1, obj, val;
wheredata.forEach(filter => {
  key = filter.field.field;

  key1 = filter.operator;
  if (filter.field.field.datatype === 'INTEGER') {
    val = parseInt(filter.value);
  } else {
    val = filter.value;
  }
  obj = {
    [key1]: val
  };

  whereuser[key] = obj;
});
console.log(whereuser);
```

But my answer is coming to as follows:

```
{ 
  email: { 'Op.eq': 'myuser@gmail.com' },
  createdAt: { 'Op.gt': '2015-12-12' } 
}
```

Notice the operators. They should actually be like [Op.eq] and [Op.gt] but with my script they are coming as 'Op.eq' and 'Op.gt'.

I am not understanding how to get these operators in the right format.

To clarify further, my node/sequelize query which works correctly is as follows, where User is a sequelize model. As you can see, I'm trying to dynamically generate the where clause.

```
User.findAll({
      where: {
        email: {[Op.eq]: 'myuser@gmail.com'},
        createdAt: {[Op.gt]: '2015-12-12'}
      }
    })
```

Comment: No, in Sequelize, it is actually [Op.eq]. You can see here. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#range-operators

Comment: `obj = {[key]: value}` is just a shorthand syntax for `obj = {}; obj[key] = value`. It would not contain `[]`. It just means you want to evaluate `key` expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Op` is an existing object (`Sequelize.Op` per the docs), and you need to turn the `"Op.eq"` string into just `eq`, so you can use bracket notation to make an expression `[Op[prop]]` that evaluates to `[Op.eq]`:

```
wheredata.forEach(filter => {
  const key = filter.field.field;
  const val = key.datatype === 'INTEGER'
    ? parseInt(filter.value)
    : filter.value;

  const { operator } = filter;
  const operatorProp = operator.split('.')[1];
  const obj = {
    [Op[operatorProp]]: val
  };

  whereuser[key] = obj;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just want to wrap them in brackets, by my understanding so you can do  this:

```
obj = {
  [`[${key1}]`]: val
};
```

Comment: I tried this and I get { email: { '[Op.eq]': 'msahajwani@gmail.com' },
  createdAt: { '[Op.gt]': '2019-12-12' } } But the problem is that it has single quotes around and my query fails again.

Answer (score 0):

Your operator must be taked from `Sequelize` module and not directly interpreted as a string.

So in your code it's not `[key1]` to use but `Op[key1.split('.')[1]]` considering `const Op = Sequelize.Op;`.

---

If you want to have it cleaner, create a function taking the operator and returning the value to use as the key, going into the Sequelize object like :

```js
const Sequelize = {
  Op: {
    gt: 'gt',
  };
};

function (operator) {
  const split = operator.split('.');
  
  return split.reduce((tmp, x) => tmp[x], Sequelize);
}
```

---

```js
const wheredata = [{
  field: {
    field: "email",
    datatype: "STRING",
    inputtype: "text",
    model: "User",
  },

  operator: "Op.eq",
  value: "myuser@gmail.com",
}, {
  field: {
    field: "createdAt",
    datatype: "DATE",
    inputtype: "date",
    model: "User",
  },
  operator: "Op.gt",
  value: "2015-12-12",
}];

const Sequelize = {
  Op: {
    gt: 'gt',
    eq: 'eq',
  },
};

const where = wheredata.reduce((tmp, x) => {
  tmp[x.field.field] = {
    [Sequelize.Op[x.operator.split('.')[1]]]: x.value,
  };

  return tmp;
}, {});

console.log(where);
```